# Time Period (Window) implementation using java + spring

Tags: java, spring, osgi, quartz-scheduler

I need to implement a time window for 5 users.according to the cron expression

1. 1st user will operate from 8AM to 10 AM.
2. 2nd user will operate from 9AM to 5 PM.

likewise.

i will run a report based on the user is in his operation time window. if it is not i just ignore that user. i am using 'OSGI' spring server to host this.

i need to know when a particular time who are the users that have the running window.

i looked at the

> org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean

to achieve this goal. is there any better option for this?

Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In other words: you have a cron tab expression and want to know if a specific time is within that expression? Is that the question? I hope not, because cron specify points in time, not ranges.

Comment: @Ralph i can have the length of the window by minutes.

Comment: within the corn expression? - can you show me an example please?

Comment: @Ralph - i am still thinking of how to do it ralph..i am having 2 attributes. one is cron and the other one will be the length (lets say 2hours from starting time). from that i need to define the window. meaning that if the cron fires monday morning 9 AM i will add 2 hours to that and window end will be 11 AM. wondering how it should be done by a scheduler. got some clue. like keep all the windows in a concurrenthashmap. still working on that..Thank you verymuch for commenting me..ideas will be really appriciate..

Comment: Do you really need a cron for this, may you find something less complex, like just the hour of the day?

Comment: @Ralph-i also proposed the same way..but it was the requirement. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `org.quartz.CronExpression` from quartz Framework, it has a method: `getNextValidTimeAfter(Date date)` that returns the next/data time after the given data time.

So a solution would may look like:

```
Date now = new Date();   
Date earlyesPossibleLogin = now - maxLoginDuration //This is psydo code, I can subtact something from a date
CronExpression cron = new CronExpression("....");
Date allowedLoginSinceEarlyestLogin = cron.getNextValidTimeAfter(earlyesPossibleLogin);
if(allowedLoginSinceEarlyestLogin > now) {
   throw new LoginDeniedException("you are out of your window.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Ralph.it work for me in a standalone application.will try it in Virgo server with OSGI nature and see..i doubt about the CronExpression class with the OSGI quartz bundle.will check that.. help highly appreciated..